# Image Transform Files Path

Tags: image-transforms, configuration

Regarding the Image Transforms and the handling of its files.

Is there a config setting that controls the location (file path) of the Image Transform Files?

By default there is automatically created a new folder which bases it name of the transform-behavior name from the CP (or the code) i.e. `_crop1920x1440` in the same directory as the original image is located.

I would like to be able to store all the transformed images in one place i.e. `/assets/transforms`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, but feel free to make a feature request!

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues